# getServiceLocator() outside Controller

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, service-locator

I have a class: `ClassA()`, i need the Doctrine Service `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');`.

I try implements the interface `ServiceManagerAwareInterface`, but the functions, `getServiceLocator()` and `setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)` not work.

Someone used the ServiceLocator outside Controller class in ZF2? It's possible?

```
<?php

namespace DbSession\Service;

use Zend\Session\SaveHandler\SaveHandlerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

/**
 * Description of SessionDB
 *
 * @author rab
 */
class SessionDB implements SaveHandlerInterface, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {
    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;
    /**
     * Session Save Path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $sessionSavePath;

    /**
     * Session Name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $sessionName;

    /**
     * Lifetime
     * @var int
     */
    protected $lifetime;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     */
    public function __construct() {
    }

    /**
     * Open the session
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public function open($savePath, $name) {
        echo "open session";
    }

    /**
     * Close the session
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public function close() {
        echo "close session";
    }

    /**
     * Read the session
     * 
     * @param int session id
     * @return string string of the sessoin
     */
    public function read($id) {

        echo "read session";
    }

    /**
     * Write the session
     * 
     * @param int session id
     * @param string data of the session
     */
    public function write($id, $data) {
        $this->getServiceLocator()->get('');
        echo "write";
    }

    /**
     * Destoroy the session
     * 
     * @param int session id
     * @return bool
     */
    public function destroy($id) {
        echo "destroy session";
    }

    /**
     * Garbage Collector
     * 
     * @param int life time (sec.)
     * @return bool
     */
    public function gc($maxlifetime) {
        echo "gc session";
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you extending any classes? What are your errors? Whats not working? Does the PC burst into flames?>

Comment: @Kisaragi my class implements another interface: `SaveHandlerInterface`. My class: class `SessionDatabase implements `SaveHandlerInterface.

I not have a PHP error, when I implements the `ServiceManagerAwareInterface`,the functions `getServiceLocator()` and `setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)` not run

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the ServiceLocatorAwareTrait (part of ZF2). If you do use that make sure your class implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface (you don't actually have to implement it as the trait does that for you, but you do have to add it to your class' implements clause).

So you get something like this:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

class ClassA implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {
    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;
}
```

Then you can just call $this->getServiceLocator() to get a hold of a servicelocator instance.

However if you just need the Doctrine entitymanager it's better practice to just inject this one dependency instead of injecting the ServiceLocator.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I implements `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` and `use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait`. But when i try `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('ServiceName')` I get an error.

PHP **Fatal error:**  Call to a member function get() on a non-object ...

My class:


`class SessionDatabase implements SaveHandlerInterface, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface  {
    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;`

Comment: Can you show your full code and point out what line you get the error on? Please put it in a code block in your original question in an Edit section so it's easier to read.

Comment: Another important thing : you must get your SessionDatabase class instance via the service manager if you want the service locator to be automatically injected.

Comment: @jmleroux and Ruben, I updated the question with my code... `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('ServiceName');` return the error

Comment: It's because you're calling it in your constructor. You can call it anywhere except in the constructor.

Comment: Ruben, I tried to put `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('ServiceName');` in other function, but ocurred same problem. My instance of class SessionDB is on onBootstrap() of the Module, it can disturb?

Comment: I'm using this module https://github.com/Mohit-Singh/DbSession. I need to use Doctrine instead of mysql_connect...

Comment: No I don't see how SessionDB could interfere with that. Please make sure getServiceLocator is returning an instance of ServiceLocatorInterface. Also make sure that you're using a recent version of ZF2, because I believe the ServiceLocatorAwareTrait was added in one of the more recent versions. And of course make sure you're using PHP version > 5.4.0, because any version older than that will not support the use of traits.

Comment: Ruben, I updated again the quetion. This is my full class. I'm using ZF2 2.3 and PHP 5.5.12. the `use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;` no set a ServiceLocator

Comment: So what happens right now? You're getting an error on calling getServiceLocator()? The argument to get() is empty right now by the way: $this->getServiceLocator()->get('');

Comment: Happens same problema. When I calling `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');`. **PHP Fatal error:**  Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Comment: How are you creating the instance of your `SessionDB` class? As per jmleroux's comment above, you have to use the service manager for this, you can't just do `$foo = new SessionDB()` or the service locator won't be automatically injected. This is the most common cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem. My class SessionDatabase() is correct. My instance was wrong.

Implements class:

```
class SessionDatabase implements SaveHandlerInterface, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {

    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

    public function write($id, $data) {
        $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    }

}
```

Instance:

```
private function initDbSession(MvcEvent $e) {

        $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        $saveHandler = new SessionDatabase();
        $saveHandler->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
}
```

Thanks everyone that helped!!! :D